# Getting a property of an object in an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Ok, so I have made an object called `Food` that has various properties describing the food (protein (in grams), calories, carbs etc). I then made a class called `Foodlist` which reads an excel sheet, creates a new `Food` object for each row of the spreadsheet (filling the object with the information in the columns of that row); the `Foodlist` class then creates an `ArrayList` of Food objects.
I now want to make a `ProteinList`, which is a sublist of `FoodList` and has a method to seperate all of the high protein foods into an array. `Proteinlist` extends `Foodlist`, how can I access the "protein" property of the Food object in the list?

Here is where my code is stuck:

```
    public Food[] groupProtein() {
        for(int i = 0; i < foodList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(foodList.get(i).protein > 6){//HERE IS THE PROBLEM, trying to get the property of the food object at i
                proteinFoods.add(foodList.get(i));
            }
        }

        Food[] temp = new Food[proteinFoods.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = proteinFoods.get(i);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: How is `protein` defined in `Food`? Publicly accessible field, or only accessed via getter/setter?

Comment: i have them all in a package. if i were to use a getter method, how would i access it? foodlist.get(i).getProtein () and store it in a local variable ?

Comment: If Food has a getter, you can do `foodList.get(i).getProtein()` Assuming `getProtein()` is the getter method.

Comment: Why don't you just place a method on your food list class, capable of returning you the subset of high protein foods?

Comment: thank you, i will try that now :), and i had not done so yet because i was confused about the syntax. i have another class that used several "." method accesssors in one line and kept receiving a strange compiler error about "unsafe methods"

Comment: How is the `foodList` arraylist defined? Are you using generics?

Comment: @A--C - he's already creating an array list of objects. Now he just has to return subsets of it based off input criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a getter for your `protein` property, your method could be:

```
public Food[] groupProtein() {
    for(Food food : foodList)
    {
        if(food.getProtein() > 6){
            proteinFoods.add(food);
        }
    }

    return proteinFoods.toArray(new Food[0]);
}
```

I suppose `proteinFoods` is a `List<Food>`... right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProteinList extends FoodList{
    //other stuff...
    public double get(int i){
        return super.get(i).getProtein();
    )
}
```

It that what you want?

Comment: 'protein" is not an object, its a property with an int value of the Food object. i don't think it can be returned as such^

Comment: is protein an `int`? or a `dobule`? or what?

Answer (score 0):

If the property `protein` is defined as `private` in your class definition, you won't be able to access it from any method outside the class. You will need to define a getter method *in* your class:

```
public class Food {
    ...
    public int getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }
    ....
}
```

Thus, you can read the value from a method outside your class:

```
foodList.get(i).getProtein()
```

I am assuming that `foodList` is properly defined, so the `get(i)` method will return a `Food` object (or whatever class it is meant to return)